# Converted my SQL to LINQ and I am getting System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported error

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-core

I am getting Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported when I try to run this LINQ Query in my C# application using EntityFrameworkCore.

This is my LINQ Query.

```
var test = 
    (from lbls1 in ctxt.Labels
    join att in ctxt.Attributes
    on lbls1.Id equals att.LabelId
    join img in ctxt.Images
    on lbls1.ImageId equals img.Id
    where att.plate_region_conf >= min_region_conf
    && att.plate_code_conf >= min_code_conf
    && states.Contains(att.plate_state)
    && cameraid.Contains(img.CameraId)
    && !exclude_filename.Contains(img.Filename)
    group lbls1 by new {
    att.plate_code,
    att.plate_state
    } into lbls1
    select lbls1).ToList()
```

This is the original SQL query I created and ran.

```
Select ImageId FROM Labels as l JOIN Attributes as a ON
        a.LabelID = l.Id
        JOIN Images as I
        On l.ImageId = I.Id
        Where 
        plate_state = states 
            AND plate_region_conf >= region_conf 
            AND plate_code_conf >= code_conf 
            AND plate_stacked = stacked 
            AND is_edge = edge
        AND I.CameraId = cameraid
        AND I.Filename <> filename
        Group By plate_code, plate_state;
```

What I read, Client-side evaluation was removed from LINQ but this should still work if this code translate to SQL. I am running MySQL and I did removed ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY so it should work.Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: So, what you want to retrieve? All filtered records but grouped? If no - add concrete projection but remember available only fields that are grouping key `plate_code, plate_state` and aggregate functions `Count`, `Avg`, etc. If yes - you have to do client-side grouping.

Comment: I'm trying to return a list of labels that been filtered by the where conditions. I'm using group by because I'm trying to remove duplicate rows in the attributes table.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `SelectMany`, which introduce rows duplication. Instead of that you have to use `Any` function in predicate and navigation property, I hope you have them.

```
var query = 
    from label in ctxt.Labels
    where 
      label.Attributes.Any(att =>
            att.plate_region_conf >= min_region_conf
         && att.plate_code_conf >= min_code_conf
         && states.Contains(att.plate_state)
      )
      && cameraid.Contains(label.Image.CameraId)
      && !exclude_filename.Contains(label.Image.Filename)
    select label;
```

If Label to Image is One to Many relation, you also has to use `Any`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, there are duplicates plate_state and plate_code that Im trying to filter out and this query does not filter them out.

Comment: plate_state and plate_code are not in projection. How they can be duplicated? Looks like you missed some details.

Comment: In the table, there is multiple rows that has the same plate_state and plate_code. The end result to have 1 of each plate_state and plate_code. I tried to achieve this through group by

Comment: which fields you need as result? plate_state and plate_code?

Comment: I dont necessarily need those fields as result, I just need the rows with duplicates of plate_state and plate_code filtered out.

Comment: It is not possible via EF to do that in one SQL and be performant. Retrieve all filtered labels with their attributes via `Include` and then filter out duplicates.